# Sorting, multiple sorting and clearing sorting selection for the Shield UI JavaScript grid

Tags: javascript, grid, shieldui

I am a newcomer to the Shield UI JavaScript Grid and am more interested in sorting of the data contained in the grid, since there isn’t quite what I am looking for in the online documentation.
I need to know how to clear a column from being selected when I switch to another one or to simply exclude a column from participating in the sorting.
I see there is this property:

```
        sorting:{
            multiple: false,
            allowUnsort: false
        },
```

does this mean that the grid is being put in the state it was before sort?

Comment: i am unclear about your need? do u need to remove the sorting of a particular column when another column is clicked?

Comment: I am trying to dig into more detail. And this is one of the things. I am able to add columns to the selection but not to turn them off for instance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to consider when talking about the Shield UI JavaScript grid.
Starting from the second part of your question- the allowUnsort property doesn’t means that this column may be excluded from the sorting filter. This happens when the user switches ascending/descending sort directions. When clicking again on the column header it will be cleared.
If you want to sort multiple columns you may do so by setting the multiple property to true as in the code given below:

```
sorting:{
    multiple: true,
},
```

This property enables quite powerful sorting by expanding the number of sorting criteria and by switching sorting directions.